# What's the meaning of bold sentences? I have difficulty in getting the meaning of thesese sentences, especially the second bold sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

He went off to work and it was just one mad panic. I knew, if I didn’t go that night, I wouldn’t do it, I just wouldn’t do it. And so, technically, yes, it was planned and I had support and back-up from me family. But if I hadn’t, I’d never have gone. If I didn’t…if I hadn’t said, right, I’m going on that Sunday night, when he’d gone off to work, I wouldn’t have done it. **I couldn’t get anything [together]. It was like, you thought this, oh, right. And that was going on all day.** I’ve arranged to go on Sunday, so I’ll just pack a few suitcases! Do you know? You can’t do that! Because, if he’d found out, I wouldn’t have been able to leave. So, when he went off to work on that Sunday morning, it was just a mad panic. QUICK! NOW! And we were putting things in bags and we just left. We just left. (Stacey)

Comment: This is what's known as an interior monologue. It's the thoughts of a character as they occur, full of faults, disjuncts, run-on meanderings—the way people actually think, as opposed to a digest of that presented for our clear understanding.

Comment: I am not seeing a quantifiable difference between the sentences in bold and the sentences not in bold. Can you specify what throws you off about these sentences in particular? As Robusto says, this is a stream of consciousness. If you get the gist of the whole thing, the details don't matter.

Comment: What does "this" refer to in "you thought this"? What's the meaning of right? Does the speaker refer to her/himself? What does "that" refer to? What's the meaning of "going on"? What's the meaning of get?! I'm totally confused !!

Comment: To 'get it together' means to get your thoughts in order (to gather your wits; to collect your thoughts). 'Right' is what you say when you are about to take decisive action; but in this case another thought, another plan interrupts.

Comment: @user378133 There is still no essential difference between the sentence in bold and those in roman. You could just as easily ask, "What does **it** refer to in *I wouldn't have done it?*" (And *right* is also used in an earlier sentence in the same way, but you haven't singled out that instance.)

Comment: You don't give the source of the passage, but it appears to be about an abused wife leaving her husband. 'This' is presumably one of the thoughts she had at different times. 'That was going on all day' = I was having confused and conflicting thoughts all day.

Comment: I think Hugh's and Bunting's opinion are true. Thanks for your precious hints.